# Reinstall mac OS x without apple ID

Tags: mac, osx-el-capitan

Iv'e found a thrown away imac from 2007 with mac os x-el capitan (don't remember version number).
when i turned it on i saw it has a password so i used the terminal in recovery mode to reset the password for one of the users as shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-4CJo7odtcU

- i wanted to erase everything on the computer and reinstall the mac os so i followed the steps specified here: [Reinstall OS X Without CD/DVD or Apple ID](https://superuser.com/questions/959422/reinstall-os-x-without-cd-dvd-or-apple-id)
- after erasing the internal disk via disk utility i tried to reinstall mac os x but i was asked to enter an apple ID and password(obviously i do not have this apple ID and i don't know who is the owner of the computer)
- only after erasing i saw the last comment saying it will still ask for apple ID in old computers
- now when i turn it on it goes straight to the recovery mode menu
- i read about a bootable flash drive option but i did not understand how to do it and from where to download this file
- is this computer doomed unusable or it can still be saved?

Comment: You very probably need a CD/DVD to wipe & reinstall an '07. They don't like booting from USB. They're not resistant to being wiped at all, there was no security back then, but if you don't clear it right down, the old ID still "owns" it.

Comment: is it possible to get this cd or make it on my own?

Comment: You can buy them on eBay. To make your own you'd need another Mac really. It's not that you need to pay for the OS - even 10.6 & 10.7 became free to download recently - it's getting the darn thing to boot properly. By about 2009 they would all boot easily from USB, by 2011 they'll boot & D/L the OS from the internet. If you have an Apple Store nearby they'll do it for you.

Comment: BTW, if you buy from eBay, you want one with a picture of a big cat, not the grey ones, which were product-specific.

Comment: did not understand what is exactly is "big cat"  lion/mountain lion?
and how i make sure it fits my specific computer? (year/ version etc..)
this is not good?: 
https://www.amazon.com/Bootable-Capitan-Install-Reinstall-Recovery/dp/B08562Q84F/ref=sr_1_17_sspa?dchild=1&keywords=bootable+el+capitan+disc&qid=1626209583&sr=8-17-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEzNVBVOU5GNVg2NVJZJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwNzgzMDc4MTdMMDM0RU5HNU5BSiZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwMTUyMTQzM0dXMUhWQUc0RldIQiZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2F0Zl9uZXh0JmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ==